# How do I truly prevent cache in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [disabling chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

I'm working on a web app that is unfortunately built around frames. Before switching to Chrome, I used the web developer toolbar in firefox to disable cache. While I would rather do this for a single site, it worked well.

In Chrome, the Dev Console -> General -> Disable cache does not work all the time, but if I manually delete the cache it works fine. Some may say to just use the hard refresh shortcut, but the nature of my application would require me logging in each time I do this.

Is there anything else I can do? This would really save me a good bit of time in Dev and its the only remaining thing I miss from firefox :/

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question they are different if similar

Answer (score 2):

click on the wrench in the upper right hand corner of chrome and select "new incognito window". Using an incognito window will fix all your caching problems. I use it sometimes when developing, its useful.

Comment: sure but not going to work on all scenarios, especially when cookies are involved :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that is not dependent on browser. If you surf to www.abc.com the browser might save data in cache. But, if you change the url, no chace will be used. So, just browse to www.abc.com?r=. This way the browser will think the page is different and will not use cache.

Hope this is help!

Comment: This won't fix issues with files (e.g. JS and images) linked from the page being viewed, which is a more likely issue in web development

Answer (score 0):

**[Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm)** is available for Chrome too. While it doesn't allow to completely disable caching it still has a very accessible "Clear cache" option.

There is also a wrench icon on the bottom right side where you can permanently disable cache. Take a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)**.